# Checkbox inside Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm, datagrid

### Issue

---

I can't seem to be able to fire a method inside my `ViewModel` when a `Checkbox` is checked inside my `DataGrid`.

Each row will have a `Checkbox` inside the row and when the `Checkbox` has been selected/unselected, I want to trigger a method in my `ViewModel` which will update a database.

### Code

---

I have this `Datagrid` inside my XAML:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg_chapters" ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters}" SelectedItem="{Binding Chapter}" SelectionMode="Single" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#e5e5e5" CellStyle="{StaticResource episodeDataGridCell}" RowHeaderWidth="0" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" CanUserResize="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Chapter" Width="90"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Appearance}" CanUserResize="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Player" Width="90"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Channel}" CanUserResize="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Channel" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mode}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Mode" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Protected}" Header="Protected" Width="80"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

As you can see at the bottom is my `Checkbox` column. In my `ViewModel` i tried to create a command to handle the selected/deselection of the `Checkbox`:

```
    public ICommand Protected
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(Protected_Click); }
    }
```

And then I created the Protected method:

```
    private void Protected_Click(object obj)
    {
        //DOES NOT HIT.
    }
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong and how I can get this functionality to work?

Comment: You are trying to bind a command as the CheckBox Value, that's not going to work.From MSDN "To populate the column, bind the column to the data by using the Binding property. The Binding property is applied to the CheckBox element created in the column." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Make a property IsChecked in your VM, bind it to CheckBox.IsCheked, and in property setter invoke your methods of db update

Comment: @Василий Шапенко Is there a way I can pass the row to which the checkbox is on?

Comment: @Ben Clarke Your ViewModel should have enough information about it, row is just a representation of some model, and you do not need it. Just write a base ViewModel with IsCheked property and virtual method UpdateDb, which you will override in child models. Or make method UpdateDb a Func, if you do not want to write much of useless(from my ppoint of view) classes

Comment: @ВасилийШапенко I already have the function to update the DB and i have successfully added the property for when the checkbox is checked a method gets fired. I am just stuck on retrieving the row information.

Comment: @ВасилийШапенко My bad, I just have to read the properties in the class! I'm stupid. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ben Clarke No problem

Answer (score 0):

**Checkbox Inside the DataGrid in DataGridTemplateColumn**

```
 <DataGrid Name="GatewayDataGrid" Width="auto" Height="auto"> 
     <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SplitMark" Width="30" >
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox x:Name="Chb" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Click="Chb_Click"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"></CheckBox>
      </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"> </DataGridTextColumn >
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" Binding="{Binding Department}"> </DataGridTextColumn >
    </DataGrid>
```